# Merge all files in a directory with a specific extension

Tags: beginner, c, file-system, file

I come from Python, with a bit a FORTRAN and Matlab some years ago. 
I'm trying to learn C. My first attempt at a program is one to merge all the files in a directory with a specified extension

```
/*
MERGE: Merges text files. Gives the ability to all files in a 
directory with specified extension.
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Function prototypes */
int append_to_file(const char *filename, const char *outfilename); // Appends the contents of filename to outfilename
int scandir(char dirname[], char const *ext, char outfile[]); // Scans a directory for files of a specific extension and merges them
bool has_extension(char const *name, char const *ext);
void usage(); // Prints out usage information (help) to the console
void path_combine(char *dest, const char *path1, const char *path2); // Combines a directory name and filename to a single filepath

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    int nfiles; // Number of files merged

    if (argc == 4)
    {
        nfiles = scandir(argv[1], argv[2], argv[3]);      
        printf("Merged %d files\n", nfiles);

        return 0;  
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Wrong input, quitting");
        return 1;
    }

}

int append_to_file(const char *filename, const char *outfilename)
{
    FILE *infile, *outfile;
    char ch;
    infile = fopen(filename, "r");
    outfile = fopen(outfilename, "a");

    if (infile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Input file is empty, skipping...\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while ((ch = fgetc(infile)) != EOF)
        fputc(ch, outfile);

    printf("Appended file\n");

    fclose(infile);
    fclose(outfile);

    return 0;

}

int scandir(char dirname[], char const *ext, char outfile[])
/* Scans a directory and merges all files of given extension */
{
    DIR *d = NULL;
    struct dirent *dir = NULL;
    char filepath[strlen(dirname) + 255];
    int i = 0;   

    d = opendir(dirname);

    if (d)
    {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
        {   
            if (has_extension(dir->d_name, ext))
            {   

                path_combine(filepath, dirname, dir->d_name);
                printf("%s\n", filepath);
                append_to_file(filepath, outfile);
                i++;
            }

        }
        closedir(d);
    }
    return i;
}


bool has_extension(char const *name, char const *ext)
{
    size_t len = strlen(name);
    return len > 4 && strcmp(name+len-4, ext) == 0;
}


void path_combine(char *dest, const char *path1, const char *path2)
{
    const char *last_char = path1;
    int append_sep = 0;
    char sep[] = "/";

#ifdef WIN32
    sep[0] = '\\';
#endif

    /* Find the last character in the first path*/
    while(*last_char != '\0')
        last_char++;

    /* If the last character is not a seperator, we must add it*/
    if (strcmp(last_char, sep) !=0)
    {
        append_sep = 1;
    }

    strcpy(dest, path1);
    if (append_sep)
        strcat(dest, sep);
    strcat(dest, path2);       

}


void usage()
{
    printf("\t=================\n");
    printf("\t      MERGE\n");
    printf("\t=================\n");
    printf("Merge two or more text files\n");
    printf("Usage:\n");
    printf("\tCall merge with a directory name and desired extension:\n");
    printf("\tmerge DIRNAME .csv OUTPUTFILE\n\n");

};
```

I realise there are many things I haven't done here (such as any real error handling), but bear in mind this is a first attempt as part of the learning process. 
Rather than being told to 'go look up xx' where xx is a whole area of learning, I'm more interested in specifics if possible.

Are there any obvious code smells? 
Is there anything that could obviously be implemented better?
Particularly usage of pointers, which I am still getting to grips with.

Answer (score 2):

- **scandir**

  It is not a good name for 2 reasons. First, it exists in a global namespace, and second, it doesn't tell what the function does. Your `scandir` not only scans the directory, but does an actual merge as well. I would recommend to scan the directory with a standard library's `scandir` and then merge files (from the list it returns) in a `merge` function.

  A perk benefit of using a stock `scandir` is an ability to control the merge order. Right now it is unpredictable.

  Yet another benefit of separating responsibilities is that *if* outfile is in the same directory with source files *and* it has an target extension, the results could be very strange.
- **has_extension** presumes that the extension is always 3 characters. It is not necessarily so. It should calculate an actual length of the `ext` argument.
- **append_to_file** produces a misleading diagnostics. The `fopen` may fail for many reasons, but file being empty is not one of them. Display the error message with `perror` or `strerror`.
- **path_combine**

  Contrary to a popular belief, windows understands a forward slash as a path separator (backslash is an artifact of `cmd.exe`). There's no need to special case windows.

  It is also not necessary to test for last character for being a separator. Just add the separator anyway, it is harmless.

  That said, I don't think that you need it at all: just `chdir()` to the source directory first.

Comment: Thanks that is very helpful. One comment on using the std library 'scandir' (I actually didn't come across that function when reading about the std lib?): using scandir then passing the resulting list to a merge function would introduce an extra loop. One to scan the directory then another to go through the list of names. If this would make no real difference (compared to writing the file) then I'm for it...

Comment: @jramm No difference in execution whatsoever. A bit more memory (for a list of filenames) would be required. Don't forget to `free()` each filename and then `free()` the list itself. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is nice.  Easily followed, well indented and well laid out.  There
is some extra whitespace that could be stripped.  I have some trivial comments:

- There are a few places where you could use braces for single statement
  loops/conditions.  Doing this avoids some common problems but is not
  universally liked (as it could be thought ugly/noisy).
- Declare all local functions `static`.  This is not so important in small
  programs but is good practice.  In large programs it avoids namespace
  pollution and may allow better optimization.  Also many people put each function before
  it is first called and put `main` last.  This avoids the need for
  local prototypes.
- Define variables at the point of first use where possible.  So instead of

  ```
  FILE *infile, *outfile;
  infile = fopen(filename, "r");
  outfile = fopen(outfilename, "a");
  ```

  do

  ```
  FILE *infile = fopen(filename, "r");
  FILE *outfile = fopen(outfilename, "a");
  ```
- Failure of `fopen` does not mean that the file was empty.  It means there
  was an error of some sort (see the value set in global `errno`).  (Clearly
  opening of output files can also fail, as can `fputc`, but I expect you know
  that - you made clear that error handling was lacking).
- `fgetc` returns an `int`.  The value of `EOF` does not necessarily fit into
  a `char` (eg if char is unsigned on your platform), so your copy loop is not
  guaranteed to terminate.  Your compiler should have warned you about that if
  you have sufficient warnings enabled.
- `has_extension` assumes an extension length of 4.  This sort of assumption
  and embedded constant is best avoided.
- `path_combine` has a confused idea of the 'separator'.  The first loop finds
  the last character of the string (actually it finds the \0).  You then do a
  `strcmp` with the separator `sep` (which incidentally could be `const`)
  which always fails (as `last_char` points to the `\0`).  The confusion is
  that the loop is looking for a *character* while `strcmp` is comparing
  strings (intended apparently to be 1 char long).  You should either base the
  test on the string in `sep` (that is, not assuming it is just 1 char) or
  just define `sep` as a `char` and compare `*last_char` with `sep`:

  ```
  char sep = '/';
  ...
  if (*last_char != sep) {...}
  ```

  Clearly you then can't do a `strcat(dest, sep)` but you should know how
  long `path1` is anyway (from the while loop - which would be better as
  `strlen` etc).
- Note that sequences of `strcpy` and `strcat` are not robust WRT string
  overflow.  String handling in C sucks.  `filepath`, into which you create
  your paths, might be better to use `PATH_MAX` from limits.h, but that does
  nothing to fix the problem of overflow.
- `scandir` (which masks the stdlib function of the same name) could take
  three `const` parameters.  Also I see no good reason to mix the `char dirname[]` and `char *ext` parameter styles - use one or the other as they mean the same
  (i.e. `*` or `[]`)
- In `scandir` I would probably return early if `opendir` fails:

  ```
  DIR *d = opendir(dirname);
  if (!d) {
      return 0;
  }
  ```

  But this is not universally approved of.  It has the advantage of reducing
  indenting in the rest of the function.  On the other hand, some coding
  standards apply a strict "one return" rule in which a function may only
  have one return.  For well written code this rule is not sensible, but
  much code is not well written.